# Posting info to Twitter with a known username / pass and the Oauth token without having to grant access

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using C# to build some functionality for a website. They want to twitter a message to their account at the point when a new vacancy gets added to their website. I face the issue that when i try to do this using the OAuth token approach i have to grant access to the application everytime. I want this all to work automatically without the need for permission. Can i login the user and then just post a message or how do I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

With OAuth you only need to get their permission once, and you can save the Access Token that Twitter returns to you and use it to act on behalf of the user as long as the user does not deny you permission to act on their behalf or the token hasn't expire.  Twitter does not currently ever expire tokens see [Twitter OAuth FAQ](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq).

Just save the token along side the username in the database and use it to send post requests whenever you need to post to twitter.

Twitter puts it this way in this [Transitioning from Basic Auth to OAuth Guide](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/basic_to_oauth):

**Prepare long-term storage for access tokens and secrets**

Whatever your storage system may be, you'll need to begin storing an **oauth_token** and **oauth_token_secret** (collectively, an "access token") for each user of your application. The oauth_token_secret should be stored securely. *Remember, you'll be accessing these values for every authenticated request your application makes to the Twitter API, so store them in a way that will scale to your user base*. When you're using OAuth, you should no longer be storing passwords for any of your users.